# Testing setInterval with jest results in wrong setInterval type being used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

So in our codebase we have a clock component which calls setInterval when it's mounted, and clearInterval when unmounted. I am trying to test that the clearInterval is called with the correct setInterval when the component is unmounted using jest. Ideally I would do the following.

```
const spyOnSetInterval = jest.spyOn(window, 'setInterval');
const spyOnClearInterval = jest.spyOn(window, 'clearInterval');

test(() => {
   spyOnSetInterval.mockReturnValueOnce(23);

   const component = mount(<DigitalClock />);
   component.unmount();

   expect(spyOnClearInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(23);

});
```

Instead I am having to do the following

```
const spyOnSetInterval = jest.spyOn(window, 'setInterval');
const spyOnClearInterval = jest.spyOn(window, 'clearInterval');

test(() => {
   spyOnSetInterval.mockReturnValueOnce((23 as unknown) as NodeJS.Timeout);

   const component = mount(<DigitalClock />);
   component.unmount();

   expect(spyOnClearInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(23);

});
```

This is due to typescript incorrectly using NodeJs.setInterval rather than window.setInterval so the return type is NodeJs.Timer rather than number.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @AdrianPascu The difference in my snippets on line 5, I am having to explicitly specify my return value as a NodeJS.Timeout due to my spy identifying window.setInterval as having this type. In reality window.setInterval has a return type of an integer and this is what I want to test without having to cast it as a Timeout.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But why is this a problem? Sure that casting it's not pretty, but there is nothing wrong to it